# Sticky AppSetting for Custom Configuration Section

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

It's possible to make an appSetting stick to a deployment slot.

[image]

Is there any way to make a setting in a Custom Config section sticky?
I would love for my Stage to point to a dummy payment processor

eg:

```
<SagePayConfiguration>    
    <add key="sagepay.api.env" value="LIVE" /><!-- override somehow in Azure app settings and set to TEST -->
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're talking about making a setting in the web.config file sticky.

That can't be done since those settings are read directly from the web.config file, and those files get swapped when you swap slots.

However, you can instead put those settings in the site's App Settings and make that setting sticky to the slot. That'll give you your desired behavior

Comment: key/val pairs in ConnectionStrings or AppSettings can be 'stuck' to a deployment slot via Powershell or the woohoo Portal (the new, weird one) - but I want an element in a different section stuck and wondered if it can be done. I swap my stage for live after a while so they can't have different .config files at src. Thanks for the suggestion tho.